# Using Sublime text 3 to build SWI prolog projects

Tags: sublimetext3, swi-prolog

Can I build with SWI prolog in sublime text on windows?

What i have tried:
I used package control to install the Prolog package here:
https://github.com/alnkpa/sublimeprolog
I have SWI prolog installed but I cannot build. Maybe the file path or name to swi is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

/JC

I get this error:

```
    [WinError 2] File not found (Det går inte att hitta filen)
    [cmd: ['swipl', '-f', '', '-t', 'main', '--quiet']]
    [dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]
    [path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Data Protection Manager\DPM\bin\VDDK\bin\]
    [Finished]
```

UPDATE-----------------------------------------------------------------------

According the suggestions by Danilo I made sure that i have a saved file with a main function in it. But i still get the same error. Any ideas?

```
[WinError 2] File not found
[cmd: ['swipl', '-f', 'testa.pl', '-t', 'main', '--quiet']]
[dir: C:\Users\psyk-jcr\Documents\Forskning\Prolog meta-analys\Kod]
[path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Data Protection Manager\DPM\bin\VDDK\bin\]
[Finished]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's happening because the build file is not well seated you need to install (PackageResourceviewer) from the package manager then:
1- from tool tab select command palette or (ctrl+shift+p)
2- search for : PackageResourceviewer: open resource and select it
3- search for your package in our case prolog and select it
4- select prolog.sublime-build
5-

```
{
    "cmd": ["swipl", "-f", "$file_name", "-t", "main", "--quiet"],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^Warning: (.+):([0-9]+)",
    "selector": "source.prolog"
}
```

change swipl to the main directory of the swiple compiler 
you need to add the main:- at the beginning

```
main:-
    likes("Name", "Another").
    likes("Name","Another") :- likes("Ahmed", "Another").
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding. I followed your instructions and changed the file, so now it looks like this: ` {
 "cmd": ["C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl", "-f", "$file_name", "-t", "main", "--quiet"],
 "working_dir": "$file_path",
 "file_regex": "^Warning: (.+):([0-9]+)",
 "selector": "source.prolog"
}`. However its still not working (nothing happens when i try to build). I have a main predicate in my file.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve my problem. As suggested by @Ahmed Elkady I updated my prolog.sublime-build with the path to swipl. In my case:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\swipl\\bin\\swipl", "-f", "$file_name", "-t", "main", "--quiet"],
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "file_regex": "^Warning: (.+):([0-9]+)",
    "selector": "source.prolog"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not saved your program in a file. Look at here

> [cmd: ['swipl', '-f', **''**, '-t', 'main', '--quiet']]

Your `sublime` build system is prepared to unify with the clause `main/0`. So your program entry point should be something like

```
main :-
    write("hello, world!\n").
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Danilo. But even when i save the file i get the same error:

Comment: Thanks Danilo! However i still get the same error, even when i made sure to save the file and have a main function (shown in my updated post).

Comment: Try the same command on the console `swipl -f tesla.pl -t main --quiet`. If you get an error it could be that the route to `swipl` is not in the `%PATH%` environment variable. If not, the error could be coming from `sublime`.